# Distinct Records Count Totals Group by Month

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a table of users where I need to run a report and show how many times the users were entered into the system for each month in a given year.  I have created a table where the first column returns the distinct users. Next, to the right, I want to show how many times the user was entered for each month.  The code I currently has only counts the totals for each month and puts the totals in every month for all users. In the case below it lists 7 for May, 13 for June, and 12 for July for every user.  But I want it to show like below where it breaks it down by month.

```
Users    May    June    July  
User1     1       2       3     
User2     1       1       2  
User3     5       10      7   

<?php
$sql = "SELECT record,count(*) as TotalCount,

(select DISTINCT count(*) from Table1 WHERE datereceived BETWEEN '2012-05-01' AND '2012-05-31') as May,
(select DISTINCT count(*) from Table1 WHERE datereceived BETWEEN '2012-06-01' AND '2012-06-30') as June,
(select DISTINCT count(*) from Table1 WHERE datereceived BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-31') as July
FROM Table1 GROUP BY record";
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql ,  $params, $options );
if( $stmt === false)
{
echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
?>  

<tr id="styling">
    <td class="style"><?php echo $row['record']; ?></td>
    <td class="style"><?php echo $row['May']; ?></td>
    <td class="style"><?php echo $row['June']; ?></td>
    <td class="style"><?php echo $row['July']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you show your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to group by your date field instead of how you use it now.

```
select DISTINCT count(*) from Table1 GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datereceived)
```

But i don't see which field you use to identify a user. You can try to group on that field as wel.

Comment: I am using record field to identify a user.  Table structure is a datetime field when user record is entered writes current date into this field, user name (record) field, and then other fields for information.  I am trying to look at the datetime field (datereceived) and separate that into separate months based on its date.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can try this one

select distinct fitstname, datename(month,datereceived), count(*) from
users group by firstname, datename(month,datereceived)

Comment: this only returned the distinct user names, but no totals for each month.